# Why to use std::move despite the parameter is an r-value reference

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move, stdmove

I am confused about using `std::move()` in below code:

If I uncomment line at (2) the output would be: `1 2 3` but if I uncomment line at (1) output would be nothing which means that move constructor of `std::vector` was called!

Why do we have to make another call to `std::move` at (1) to make move constructor of `std::vector` to be called?

What I understood that `std::move` get the `r-value` of its parameter so, why we have to get the `r-value` of `r-value` at (1)?

I think this line `_v = rv;` at (2) is more logical and should make `std::vector` move constructor to be called without `std::move`because `rv` itself is `r-value` reference in the first place.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    void set(std::vector<T> & lv)
    {

    }  
    void set(std::vector<T> && rv)
    {           
        //_v = std::move(rv);          (1)
        //_v = rv;                     (2)
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _v;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
    A<int> a;

    a.set(std::move(vec));
    for(auto &item : vec)
        cout << item << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Every named object is a Lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since
> C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as std::cin or
> std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the**
> **expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

`vector` has two overloads of assignment operator, one for Lvalue reference and another for Rvalue reference.

```
vector::operator=(const vector&) // copy assignment operator
vector::operator=(vector&&) // move assignment operator
```

Overload which takes Lvalue reference is called when Lvalue is passed as argument for `operator=`.
[Details here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

> when a function has both rvalue reference and lvalue reference
> overloads, the rvalue reference overload binds to rvalues (including
> both prvalues and xvalues), while the lvalue reference overload binds
> to lvalues

By `std::move(rv);` you cast `rv` - Lvalue to Rvalue reference, and `operator=` which takes Rvalue reference is called. Otherwise, Lvalue binds to Lvalue reference and vector is copied instead of being moved.